# Choose which ViewController will display initially

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to select which ViewController the AppDelegate should display based in a `NSUserDefaults` BOOL. But the `HomeViewController` does not display.
I'm using Storyboards and I have my own class of `UINavigationController`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [FBLoginView class];
    [FBProfilePictureView class];

    MeuNavigationController *nav = [[MeuNavigationController alloc]init];
    if ([NSUD boolForChave:@"firstLogin"]==false) {
        ViewController *viewC = [[ViewController alloc]init];
        [nav pushViewController:viewC animated:NO];
    }else{
        HomeViewController *viewP = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];
        [nav pushViewController:viewP animated:NO];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [FBLoginView class];
    [FBProfilePictureView class];

    UIViewController *controller = nil;
    if ([NSUD boolForChave:@"firstLogin"]==false) {
        controller = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    }else{
        controller = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = [[MenuNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

You noted that you're doing this off of storyboard. You might want to consider making this change as well:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [FBLoginView class];
    [FBProfilePictureView class];

                                                                // Name of storyboard
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *controller = nil;
    if ([NSUD boolForChave:@"firstLogin"]==false) {
        controller = [[ViewController alloc]init];
                                                                        // Set this in the storyboard's identity inspector
        controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    }else{
        controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = [[MenuNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

But you ask... Mr. jakenberg, how does one set their unique view controller identifier?

[image]

Cheers

Comment: Thank You... Mr. jakenberg, you made my day, I was sad because Brazil lost for 7x1 and now I am happy! heheheheh

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to be kind and click that little green checkmark to answer this q correct ;) Welcome to Stack Overflow